# Get DLL name with PyDBG and System_dll.py?

Tags: debugging, debuggers, dll, python

Is it possible to get the name and path of a DLL that is loaded by the application using PyDBG and System_dll.py? I have a script and PyDBG handles loaded dlls with just:
`dbg.set_callback(LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT, handler_print_dll_loaded)`

Is there a way to get the loaded DLL's using tools in pydbg to return somthing similar to Immunity Debuggers `Log Data` window:

`67EE0000   Module C:\windows\SYSTEM32\OLEPRO32.DLL
 69E20000   Module C:\windows\SYSTEM32\oledlg.dll
 6F5E0000   Module C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
 6F7F0000   Module C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
 etc...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**:>type ENUMMODS.PY**

```
import sys
from pydbg import * 
for modules in pydbg().attach(int(sys.argv[1])).enumerate_modules():
    print modules
pydbg().detach()
```

**:>ENUMMODS.PY**

```
('calc.exe', 12517376L)
('ntdll.dll', 1999765504L)
('kernel32.dll', 1970733056L)
('KERNELBASE.dll', 1968111616L)
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
('oleacc.dll', 1836253184L)
```